# Mutate variable depending on getting a value on any variable containing a string in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where I am trying to mutate a variable where it takes value of 1 if any of a number of other columns take the value of 1.

Basically I have multiple variables which contain `resavoid1` in their name and I want to create a new column `avoid` which == 1 if a row has a value of 1 in any of the columns whose name contains `resavoid1` or zero if not.

This is a smal dput of my dataframe:

```
    structure(list(pidp = structure(c(22445, 280165, 387605, 541285, 
599765, 665045, 813285, 1731965, 1833965, 2297045, 2853965, 3565925, 
3663845, 3667245, 3705325, 4091565, 4454005, 4473725, 4626045, 
4626725), label = "cross-wave person identifier (public release)   ", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    pid = structure(c(10127798, 12430439, 13361163, 14396769, 
    14757249, 15270041, 16441141, 45754268, 50832336, 77185978, 
    96577029, 118692798, 119065835, 119074613, 119277506, 135447429, 
    154358304, 154588539, 164246088, 164246118), label = "personal identifier (BHPS cohort)", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    e_fnpid = structure(c(-8, -8, 341490565, 137280445, -8, -8, 
    544803765, -8, -8, 409500085, -8, -8, 435306085, -8, -8, 
    489864529, -8, -8, -8, -8), label = "Natural father: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_mnpid = structure(c(272012925, 
    750828805, 341490569, 137280449, 205591205, 205598685, 544803769, 
    477995125, 748184965, -8, -8, 3564565, 435306089, 299941205, 
    -8, 489864525, -8, -8, -8, -8), label = "Natural mother: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_pn1pid = structure(c(272012925, 
    750828805, 341490565, 137280445, 205591205, 205598685, 544803765, 
    477995125, 748184965, 409500085, -8, 3564565, 435306085, 
    299941205, -8, 489864525, -8, -8, -8, -8), label = "Natural parent 1: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_pn2pid = structure(c(-8, -8, 
    341490569, 137280449, -8, -8, 544803769, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, 435306089, -8, -8, 489864529, -8, -8, -8, -8), label = "Natural parent 2: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_pns1pid = structure(c(272012925, 
    750828805, 341490565, 137280445, 205591205, 205598685, 544803765, 
    477995125, 748184965, 409500085, -8, 3564565, 435306085, 
    299941205, -8, 489864525, -8, -8, -8, -8), label = "Nat/step/adopt parent 1: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_pns2pid = structure(c(-8, -8, 
    341490569, 137280449, -8, 205598689, 544803769, 477995137, 
    -8, -8, -8, -8, 435306089, -8, -8, 489864529, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8), label = "Nat/step/adopt parent 2: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_grfpid = structure(c(-8, -8, 
    -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -8, -8), label = "Grandfather: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_grmpid = structure(c(-8, -8, 
    -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 409500089, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -8, -8, -8, -8), label = "Grandmother: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_hrpid = structure(c(272012925, 
    750828805, 341490565, 137280445, 205591205, 205598685, 544803765, 
    477995125, 748184965, 409500089, 690118488, 3564565, 435306085, 
    299941205, 164178525, 489864529, 4454005, 4473725, 4626045, 
    4626045), label = "Household reference person: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    e_ppid = structure(c(-8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 411978685, 4626725, 4626045
    ), label = "partner's person identifier: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_sppid = structure(c(-8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 411978685, 
    4626725, 4626045), label = "Spouse's person identifier: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_fnspid = structure(c(-8, -8, 
    341490565, 137280445, -8, 205598689, 544803765, 477995137, 
    -8, 409500085, -8, -8, 435306085, -8, -8, 489864529, -8, 
    -8, -8, -8), label = "Nat/step/adopt father: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_mnspid = structure(c(272012925, 
    750828805, 341490569, 137280449, 205591205, 205598685, 544803769, 
    477995125, 748184965, -8, -8, 3564565, 435306089, 299941205, 
    -8, 489864525, -8, -8, -8, -8), label = "Nat/step/adopt mother: PIDP", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_sex = structure(c(2, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), label = "sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    male = 1, female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double")), e_bosssex = structure(c(-8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, 
    -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "sex of boss ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    male = 1, female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double")), e_cowosexn = structure(c(-8, -8, -8, -7, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8
    ), label = "number of co-workers female ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    e_cowosexp = structure(c(-8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "proportion of co-workers female ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `0 in 10` = 0, `1 in 10` = 1, `2 in 10` = 2, `3 in 10` = 3, 
    `4 in 10` = 4, `5 in 10` = 5, `6 in 10` = 6, `7 in 10` = 7, 
    `8 in 10` = 8, `9 in 10` = 9, `10 in 10` = 10, `can t say` = 98
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    e_sexuor = structure(c(-8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, 
    -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "sexual orientation  ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `heterosexual or straight` = 1, `gay or lesbian` = 2, bisexual = 3, 
    other = 4, `prefer not to say` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_scwhorusex = structure(c(1, 4, 
    2, -7, 3, 3, -7, 1, 2, -7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 8, -7, 2, 1), label = "important who you are: gender   ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `very important to my sense of who i am` = 1, `fairly important to my sense of who i am` = 2, 
    `not very important to my sense of who i am` = 3, `not at all important to my sense of who i am` = 4, 
    `don't know/doesn't apply` = 8), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_ppsex = structure(c(-8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 2, 
    2, 1), label = "Partner's sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, male = 1, 
    female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
    )), e_pn1sex = structure(c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    -8, 2, 1, 2, -8, 2, -8, -8, -8, -8), label = "Natural parent 1: Sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, male = 1, 
    female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
    )), e_pn2sex = structure(c(-8, -8, 2, 2, -8, -8, 2, -8, -8, 
    -8, -8, -8, 2, -8, -8, 1, -8, -8, -8, -8), label = "Natural parent 2: Sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, male = 1, 
    female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
    )), e_pns1sex = structure(c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    -8, 2, 1, 2, -8, 2, -8, -8, -8, -8), label = "Nat/step/adopt parent 1: Sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, male = 1, 
    female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
    )), e_pns2sex = structure(c(-8, -8, 2, 2, -8, 1, 2, 1, -8, 
    -8, -8, -8, 2, -8, -8, 1, -8, -8, -8, -8), label = "Nat/step/adopt parent 2: Sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, male = 1, 
    female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
    )), e_sex_dv = structure(c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), label = "Sex, derived", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, inconsistent = 0, 
    Male = 1, Female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double")), e_dvage = structure(c(28, 34, 25, 27, 26, 31, 
    43, 22, 48, 16, 31, 23, 29, 25, 59, 35, 68, 57, 77, 75), label = "age from date of birth or ageif ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    e_maage = structure(c(-8, 48, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, 
    -7, 54, -8, -8, -8, 86, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "mother s age", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    e_paage = structure(c(62, 64, -8, -7, 54, -8, -7, 52, -8, 
    -7, 64, 47, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "father s age", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    e_ageret = structure(c(-8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, 
    -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "age expected to retire  ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    e_heritage1 = structure(c(0, -9, 0, -7, -9, -9, -7, 0, 1, 
    -7, 1, 0, 0, -9, 0, 1, 0, -7, 0, 0), label = "historical sites: a city or town with historic character", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_heritage2 = structure(c(1, -9, 
    0, -7, -9, -9, -7, 1, 1, -7, 1, 0, 0, -9, 1, 1, 0, -7, 0, 
    0), label = "historical sites: a historic building open to the public (non-religious)", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_heritage3 = structure(c(0, -9, 
    0, -7, -9, -9, -7, 1, 1, -7, 1, 0, 0, -9, 0, 0, 0, -7, 0, 
    0), label = "historical sites: a historic park or garden open to the public  ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_heritage4 = structure(c(0, -9, 
    0, -7, -9, -9, -7, 0, 0, -7, 1, 0, 0, -9, 0, 1, 0, -7, 0, 
    0), label = "historical sites: a place connected with industrial history (e.g. an old fact   ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_heritage5 = structure(c(0, -9, 
    1, -7, -9, -9, -7, 0, 0, -7, 1, 0, 0, -9, 1, 1, 0, -7, 0, 
    0), label = "historical sites: a historic place of worship attended as a visitor (not to w   ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_heritage6 = structure(c(1, -9, 
    0, -7, -9, -9, -7, 0, 0, -7, 1, 0, 0, -9, 0, 1, 0, -7, 0, 
    0), label = "historical sites: a monument such as a castle, fort or ruin ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_heritage7 = structure(c(0, -9, 
    0, -7, -9, -9, -7, 0, 0, -7, 0, 0, 0, -9, 0, 1, 0, -7, 0, 
    0), label = "historical sites: a site of archaeological interest (e.g. roman villa, ancien   ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_heritage8 = structure(c(0, -9, 
    0, -7, -9, -9, -7, 0, 0, -7, 0, 0, 0, -9, 0, 0, 0, -7, 0, 
    0), label = "historical sites: a site connected with sports heritage (e.g. wimbledon) (not   ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_heritage96 = structure(c(0, -9, 
    0, -7, -9, -9, -7, 0, 0, -7, 0, 1, 1, -9, 0, 0, 1, -7, 1, 
    1), label = "historical sites: none of these things  ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_scwhoruage = structure(c(1, 4, 
    2, -7, 3, 4, -7, 2, 2, -7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, -7, 3, 1), label = "important who you are: age/life stage   ", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `very important to my sense of who i am` = 1, `fairly important to my sense of who i am` = 2, 
    `not very important to my sense of who i am` = 3, `not at all important to my sense of who i am` = 4, 
    `don't know/doesn't apply` = 8), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_scage1drnk = structure(c(11, 
    13, 15, -7, 18, 17, -7, 15, 16, -7, 13, 12, 16, 16, 19, 15, 
    -8, -7, 19, 19), label = "age of first alcoholic drink", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    e_age_if = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), label = "Imputation flag for age_dv", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, `nothing imputed` = 0, 
    `(partly) imputed` = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double")), e_age_dv = structure(c(28, 34, 25, 27, 26, 31, 
    43, 22, 48, 16, 31, 23, 29, 25, 59, 35, 68, 57, 77, 75), label = "Age, derived from dob_dv and intdat_dv", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_agegr5_dv = structure(c(6, 7, 
    6, 6, 6, 7, 9, 5, 10, 4, 7, 5, 6, 6, 12, 8, 14, 12, 15, 15
    ), label = "Age group (age_dv): 5 year intervals", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, `0-4 years old` = 1, 
    `5-9 years old` = 2, `10-14 years old` = 3, `15-19 years old` = 4, 
    `20-24 years old` = 5, `25-29 years old` = 6, `30-34 years old` = 7, 
    `35-39 years old` = 8, `40-44 years old` = 9, `45-49 years old` = 10, 
    `50-54 years old` = 11, `55-59 years old` = 12, `60-64 years old` = 13, 
    `65-69 years old` = 14, `70 years or older` = 15), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_agegr10_dv = structure(c(3, 4, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 6, 4, 7, 6, 8, 8), label = "Age group (age_dv): 10 year intervals", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, `0-9 years old` = 1, 
    `10-19 years old` = 2, `20-29 years old` = 3, `30-39 years old` = 4, 
    `40-49 years old` = 5, `50-59 years old` = 6, `60-69 years old` = 7, 
    `70 years or older` = 8), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double")), e_agegr13_dv = structure(c(5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
    8, 4, 9, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5, 11, 7, 13, 11, 13, 13), label = "Age group (age_dv): 13 categories", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, `0-15 years old` = 1, 
    `16-17 years old` = 2, `18-19 years old` = 3, `20-24 years old` = 4, 
    `25-29 years old` = 5, `30-34 years old` = 6, `35-39 years old` = 7, 
    `40-44 years old` = 8, `45-49 years old` = 9, `50-54 years old` = 10, 
    `55-59 years old` = 11, `60-64 years old` = 12, `65 years or older` = 13
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    e_resavoid1_1 = structure(c(-8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 1: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_resavoid1_2 = structure(c(-8, 
    -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 2: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_resavoid1_3 = structure(c(-8, 
    -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 3: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_resavoid1_4 = structure(c(-8, 
    -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 4: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_resavoid1_5 = structure(c(-8, 
    -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 5: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_resavoid1_6 = structure(c(-8, 
    -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 6: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_resavoid1_7 = structure(c(-8, 
    -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 7: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_resavoid1_8 = structure(c(-8, 
    -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 8: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_resavoid1_9 = structure(c(-8, 
    -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 9: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_resavoid1_10 = structure(c(-8, 
    -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 10: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_resavoid1_11 = structure(c(-8, 
    -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 11: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), e_resavoid1_12 = structure(c(-8, 
    -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, 
    -8, -7, -8, -8), label = "avoid place no. 12: reasons avoided places: your sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(missing = -9, 
    inapplicable = -8, proxy = -7, refusal = -2, `don't know` = -1, 
    `not mentioned` = 0, mentioned = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I want is to have a variable takes the value of 1 if any of the variables containing `resavoid1` == 1 and taking the value of 0 if not.

I tried different things like:

```
library(tidyverse)
    df%>% 
  mutate(avoid = ifelse(any(contains("resavoid1") == 1), 1, 0))
```

But I never quite get what I am looking for or I get errors thrown at me.

I appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upvoted @Gregor's answer but for those still playing with the new `dplyr` `across` semantics an equivalent solution

```r
df %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(avoid = as.integer(sum(c_across(contains("resavoid"))) > 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `ifelse` is that, unlike `if(){}else{}`, it works on vectors that are all the same length - the input must be the same length as the output. Your input test is `any()` which has a length 1 result, so you'll only get 1 value out of `ifelse`, whereas you need one value per row.

I think this should work:

```
df = df %>%
  mutate(avoid = as.integer(rowSums(select(., matches("resavoid"))) > 0))
```

I can't really tell - the 59 columns you shared are a little overwhelming, and at a glance it doesn't look like the any of the `resavoid` columns you shared contain `1` values.

I'd suggesting using a sample of data with, say, 2 non-resavoid columns and 2 or 3 resavoid columns with some `1`s in them, then you'll be able to easily see what's going on.

```
df_test = data.frame(
  x = 1:4,
  hello = 4:1,
  e_resavoid1_12 = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
  e_eresavoid1_8 = c(0, 0, 1, 1)
)

## looks right
df_test %>%  
  mutate(avoid = as.integer(rowSums(select(., matches("resavoid"))) > 0))
#   x hello e_resavoid1_12 e_eresavoid1_8 avoid
# 1 1     4              0              0     0
# 2 2     3              0              0     0
# 3 3     2              1              1     1
# 4 4     1              0              1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `rowSums`

```
 df_test$avoid <- +(rowSums(df_test[grepl("resavoid", names(df_test))]) > 0)
```